# show data with join table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to show all reservation of user this is my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservation` (
```

`id_passager` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idvoyage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `etat` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dateres` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_passager`,`idvoyage`),
  KEY `iduser` (`id_passager`,`idvoyage`),
  KEY `idvoyage` (`idvoyage`)
);

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trajet` (
```

`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `villedep` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `villearrivee` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
```

`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `datenaiss` date NOT NULL,
  `sexe` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `numtel` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `mdp` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `imageprofil` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nbsignal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pseudo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `musique` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fumeur` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bavardage` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexecovoiturage` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `numtel` (`numtel`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pseudo` (`pseudo`)
);

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicule` (
```

`matricule` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `marque` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `modele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `confort` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `couleur` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `image1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_utilisateur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`matricule`),
  KEY `id_utilisateur` (`id_utilisateur`)
);

and this is my controller function:

```
public function reservation()
{
    $this->load->view('headerprofile');
    $data['reservation']=$this->User_model->getReservation();
    $this->load->view('trajet/reservation',$data);
    $this->load->view('footerprofile');
}
```

this is my model:

```
function getReservation()
{
    $results = array();

    $id=$this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->db->select('res.*, v.*, t.*');
    $this->db->from('reservation AS res, voyage AS v, trajet AS t,user AS u,vehicule AS veh ');
    $this->db->where('res.id_passager',$id);
    $this->db->where('u.id',$id);
    $this->db->where('res.idvoyage=v.id');
    $this->db->where('t.id=v.id_trajet');
    $this->db->where('veh.id_utilisateur',$id);
    //$this->db->where('v.id_vehicule=veh.matricule');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>1)
    {
        $results =$query->result();
    }
   return $results;
}
```

Comment: show your table

Comment: Can You Please Elaborate the names of the table columns.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to include the join in there somewhere. I'm not cool enough to remember your foreign keys and write out an example that you can paste directly into your code, but you have to:

```
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.index = table1.index');
```

You can specify the type of join if needed. Refer to the manual for a more thorough explanation, in case you're trying to do something fancy.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html